# How to hide jquery dialog before the open event?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a button that triggers a popup as follows. I pull some info from server side to display it on the popup. The thing is that it takes a while to pull up the info on server side and my dialog opens up as empty and then show the info after 1-2 seconds. It's annoying. Is there a way to show the dialog only when the server side info is ready?

```
function openPopup(id)
    {
        $("#divPopup").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Popup Title',
            buttons: {
                OK: function () {                        
                    //TODO
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                // Can I hide the dialog popup before the info is ready?
                populateInfo(id);
                addDialogBGConfirm($(this).parent().css('z-index') - 1);
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                removeDialogBGConfirm();
            }
        });
    }

    function populateInfo(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: window.location.href + "/GetServerSideInfo",
            data: "{'profileId': '" + id + "'}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                // populate popup controls based on server side info
                $('.pname').text(res.d[0]);
                // ...                         

            },
            error: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert('Error in calling method');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: showing a loading animation inside popup is better approach, what you are asking can encourage user to click button twice to open popup (assuming it opens on click of some button).

Comment: Thanks! But I want to hide all the controls before the server side info is ready. I tried to put a display:none css in the first line of open but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: how about opening the dialog after the ajax completes? P.S I actually support @yogi 's solution

Comment: @VictorRadu lol yes!! My brain was frozen just now. Yeah I got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap a `Promise` around your `openPopup(id)`.

For example if you fetch a file locally and use it after it is loaded, it should look like

```
$.get("data/file.txt").then(useFile);
```

with `useFile` being a function that handles `file.txt` content.

For more info check http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this by showing a loading animation inside the popup as what @yogi suggested. That's by simply create a loading div in my popup HTML and then add the following at the end of the $.ajax success method:

```
 $('.loading').css("display", "none"); // loading animation div
 $('.InfoSection').css("display", "block"); // real content
```